# "Blood in our veins" meaning

Tags: meaning, expressions

In the series "The Wire" there's a conversation between the mayor and the police commander that goes like this:

> - Can't you have police sit on locations where the homeless
>   gather? Monitor them like that?
>
> - And still answer the calls? Not without doubling up post units, which means overtime.
>
> - Overtime, again.
>
> - *Blood in our veins, Mr. Mayor*.

That's an interesting expression; I haven't heard it before.

My guess is he means his staff are not superhuman and can only do so much, but I'm not sure. So what does it mean? I couldn't find anything relevant googling the phrase so I'd also be interested if you know of any references.

Comment: It's not exactly a "standard" expression, but I'd guess what the police commander means is something akin to *[It's all] **grist to our mill*** (i.e. - working overtime isn't a problem for us - in fact, that's what we *depend* on to make up our wages*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes I figured it's not standard when I couldn't find anything. Just to give a little more context, the commander has been pushing to allow overtime previously but the mayor has said there's not enough budget for that, so the mayor's _"Overtime, again"_ is an expression of discontent of the matter being brought up again.

Comment: Well, it's clearly a "dismissive" response. Perhaps a closer paraphrasing might be *It's what we live by, Mr Mayor* (or more quirkily, *That's what makes **our** world go round!*).

Comment: It means that working overtime for us is just normal, like the blood in our veins. These writers try to avoid cliches, and here the writer has done so beautifully. And it is not dismissive. It's just saying this is normal. I have seen The Wire but I do not remember the scene. Only the tone of voice can determine whether or not it was intended dismissively.

Comment: @Lambie: I haven't watched it either, but I maintain that just the fragment we have here strongly suggests the response ***is*** "dismissive". Particularly bearing in mind what OP here says about preceding context, it seems clear the police chief is effectively saying "Tough shit! That's how things work with us!" when the mayor rails against the fact that solving his problem will rack up a big overtime bill.

Comment: There is no way to tell, his tone might not be sarcastic or dismissive. It could be emphatic or declarative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reminds me somewhat of Shylock's soliloquy  in The Merchant of Venice, i.e. the policemen are simply human, and in the OP's quote not super-human.

> **If you prick us, do we not bleed?** if you tickle us, do we not laugh? if you poison us, do we not die? and if you wrong us, shall we not revenge? If we are like you in the rest, we will resemble you in that.

Comment: That's an interesting reference, thanks. Having read the comments and watched the scene again multiple times, I think he either means this, i.e. the policemen are simply human and can't do much more than they're doing in the time they're being allowed to work, or he's referring to _overtime_ itself saying it's like "blood in our veins" like @FumbleFingers says, not as in _normal_, but more literally meaning it keeps the force _alive_, allowing them to function properly and do their job.